# Error bounds for $e$

Tags: calculus, exponential-function

Prove that for all $n\in\mathbb{N}_+$, we have $$(1+\frac{1}{n})^n>\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!}-\frac{e}{2n}.$$

Comment: Have you tried the binomial theorem on the left-hand side?

Comment: @ncmathsadist: I am curious; is there any easy argument with binomial theorem?

Comment: I haven't but I thought there might be some kind of trick lying there.  The log method, shown below, it seems to me is the most transparent and elegant way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that when $x>0$, we have:
$$\log(1+x)>x-\frac{x^2}{2},\quad e^{-x}>1-x.$$
It follows that
$$(1+\frac{1}{n})^n=e^{n\log(1+\frac{1}{n})}>e^{n(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2n^2})}=e\cdot e^{-\frac{1}{2n}}>e(1-\frac{1}{2n})>\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k!}-\frac{e}{2n}.$$

Answer (score 0):

First,if $\forall 1 \le i \le n , a_i \gt -1$,then we have:
$$\prod_{i=1}^n(1+a_i) \gt 1 + \sum_{i=1}^na_i.$$

Then:
$$\begin{aligned}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n &= \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{n^{\underline{i}}}{n^i}\frac{1}{i!}\\
&=2 + \sum_{i=2}^n(\prod_{j=0}^{i-1}(1-\frac{j}{n}))\frac{1}{i!}\\
&\gt 2 + \sum_{i=2}^n(1-\frac{i(i-1)}{2n})\frac{1}{i!}
\\&=2 + \sum_{i=2}^n\frac{1}{i!} - \sum_{i=0}^{n-2}\frac{1}{2n}\frac{1}{i!}
\\&=\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{1}{i!}-\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}\frac{1}{2n}\frac{1}{i!}
\\ &\gt \sum_{i=0}^n\frac{1}{i!}-\frac{e}{2n}
\end{aligned}$$